# Nothing is happening after solving FunCaptcha

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, twitter, captcha, 2captcha

I'm using 2Captcha to solve FunCaptcha for Twitter, and I'm getting the solved token, I'm changing both fc-token and verification-token values to the solved answer and nothing is happening.

```
 solver = TwoCaptcha(api_key)
    result = solver.funcaptcha(sitekey=f'{pk}', url=f'https://twitter.com/i/flow/signup/', surl='https://client-api.arkoselabs.com')
    token = str(result)

driver.execute_script(f"document.getElementsByName('fc-token')[0].setAttribute('value', '{token}');")
    driver.execute_script(f"document.getElementsByName('verification-token')[0].setAttribute('value', '{token}');")
```

And I've checked in Chrome's developer tool that their values are indeed changing. Now 2Captcha page says we have to change the value of fc-token (which I did), however nothing is happening, nothing is changing or refreshing or loading. How do I pass the captcha after and authenticate after from here ?